# Is it possible to use conditional inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using Material UI and CardHeader is a component (the top part of a  post). I want to render 2 button on the post if the post (`isUser = true` )is posted by the user. Is that possible?

```
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "red" }} aria-label="recipe">
                        U
                    </Avatar>
                }

                title={username}
                
                {isUser && (
                    <Box display="flex">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleEdit} sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
                            <EditIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
                            <DeleteForeverIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Box>
                )}
            />
```

Comment: What prop should you be assigning those buttons to? Where should they appear in the card?

Comment: these are the props being passed to the `Post` component.  The `CardHeader` is one part of the post component. All component shown on my code in this post are component from MUI. 
                        isUser={true}
                        key={index}
                        username={user.username}
                        caption={post.caption}
                        selectedFile={post.selectedFile}
                        createAt={post.createAt}

Comment: That's not what I was asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want those buttons to appear in the card header's *action* area, you just need to assign them to the `action` prop...

```jsx
<CardHeader
  avatar={
    <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "red" }} aria-label="recipe">
      U
    </Avatar>
  }
  title={username}
  action={
    isUser && (
      <Box display="flex">
        <IconButton onClick={handleEdit} sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
          <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
          <DeleteForeverIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    )
  }
/>;
```

For more details on the component's available props, see [the documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-header/#props).